# Python array convert to integer and add together?

Tags: python, list

I was just playing around with this python code. I would simply like to know how to convert the string represented numbers in the array to integers and then subtract the value of one from the other?

The array I have used is just an example.

```
x = 0
results1 = ["8", "2", "3","1"]
while x != len(results1):
  firstthing1 = results1[x]
  x = x+1
  firstthing2 = results1[x]
  print(int(firstthing1) + int(firstthing2))
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing now? Just use `-` instead of `+` ?

Comment: doesn't work invalid literal for int() with base 10,error pops up doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you mean by `subtract the value of one from the other` perhaps an example or the expected output would make it clearer.

Comment: A good rule of thumb with python is this: if you find yourself using a loop, there's probably a better way to do it

Comment: So apparently you have some invalid values - Should you ignore them? Treat them as `0` or something else?

Comment: @user3739465 that error literally means your string isn't a base10 number. Are you not passing in a number?

Comment: subtract  results1[0] - results1[1]

Comment: am passing a variable that points to a array element

Comment: The code you are running is not the code you have posted in the question.  Your actual code contains a different set of elements in the list and one of them is not convertible to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
results1 = ["8", "2", "3","1"]
print([ int(x) - int(y) for x,y in zip(results1, results1[1:]+[0])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will substitute `0` for values that can't be converted to `int`

```
from itertools import tee
results1 = ["8", "2", "foo", "3","1"]


def result_gen(seq):
    for item in seq:
        try:
            yield int(item)
        except ValueError:
            yield 0  # or pass if you want to ignore bad values


first, second = tee(result_gen(results1))
next(second)


for i, j in zip(first, second):
    print(i + j) # or print(i - j) or print (j - i) etc.
```